# Haskell: Alternative to patterns of where f = foo e, e = bar d, d = baz c

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, where-clause

I have a function which is growing and which is getting a where pattern like what is shown bellow. What is the proper alternative to these where f = fooed e which is equal to bared e which is equal to bazed d...?

```
myFunc:: String -> Options -> String
myFunc someString opts = topStr ++ editedMidStr ++ botStr
    where editedMidStr  = foo f
          f             = bar e
          e             = baz d
          d             = qux c
          ...           = ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use function composition!

```
myFunc myString opts = topStr ++ editedMidStr ++ botStr where
  editedMidStr = (foo . bar . baz . qux . makeACFromMyString) myString
```

Comment: So this is what these dots are doing! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The most obvious way is to simply put every argument in parens:

```
   where editedMidStr = foo (bar (baz ... (qux x)...))
```

However this is ugly and makes it hard to see what's matching. It's generally preferred in Haskell to avoid parens if possible in favour of the "parenthesation operator"

> Prelude> :i $
>   ($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
>   infixr 0 $

This is really just an infix like `+` or `==`, except that it doesn't do anything but keep the arguments on both sides apart. The LHS is a function which is applied to the RHS. So you can write `bar (baz q)` as `bar $ baz q`. And because the `$` is right-associative, you can prepend more functions:

```
    foo (bar (baz q)) ≡ foo $ bar $ baz q
```

That is pretty neat and concise, however it can still be rewritten as something more elegant.
This very common immediately-hand-the-result-to-another-function paradigm is called *function composition*.

```
    foo (bar (baz q)) ≡ (foo . bar . baz) q
```

Why would we prefer this? For one thing, it's more refactoring-friendly. If the pipeline becomes too long, you can just take out any chunk of it and give it a meaningful name.

The nicest form IMO is to use both composition and `$`:

```
    foo . bar . baz $ q
```

or

```
    foo . bar $ baz q
```